# Need to get request and response body and head in web Api2 project .How can i do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web

Web Api2 project,,,Controller inherited from another controller ,,,,need to get every request's and response's body and head in json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to intercept the request using the `DelegatingHanler` 
something like  the following

```
public class IntercepterMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            //try to manipulate the request object

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```